# jquery html(); without button style

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

In Jquery mobile I try to replace my header with some buttons. I do it with the html() function from jquery.

The problem is the icons from the buttons get lost, and don't look like the original div..

How can I solve it?
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zoutepopcorn/3hGJa/)

**HTML**:

```
<div data-role="page" id="index">
      <div id="header" data-theme="b" data-role="header">
          <h1>replace this with some buttons</h1>
      </div>

      <div data-role="content">
          <div id="map"></div>
      </div>
</div>

<!-- div to instert-->
<span id="downBut"><center>
  <button type="submit" id="down" style="width: 110px" data-mini="true"  data-theme="a" data-transition="pop" data-icon="carat-d">Download</button>
  <button type="submit" id="down" style="width: 110px" data-mini="true"  data-theme="a" data-transition="pop" data-icon="delete">cancel</button>
</center></span>
```

**Javascript**:

```
// make the from header buttons
$("#header").html($("#downBut"));
```

**Css**:

```
.ui-header {
    height: 40px;
}

.ui-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0;
}
h1 {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: You have two buttons with the same id `down` and not identical styling. Change it to different id's for each button or give them classes instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call `create` for `header` div after replacing html with buttons.

```
$('#header').html($('#downBut'));
$('#header').trigger('create');
```

**[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3hGJa/20/)**

Comment: This is because the buttons are originally outside of the `data-role="page"` div, so they are not "enhanced" by jQuery mobile when it first creates the page.

Comment: exactly what i wanted. Thank you